# Amazon S3 mp4 video not playing in HTML video tag

Tags: html, video, amazon-s3, mp4

I am uploading video to S3 from android.
But is it not playing in 
 in html in chrome
here the video link :

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/anti-theft21/uploads/vid_1472562519vRqe5NjXgOEYUfFuWLRnXf8bpao8HR.mp4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your video is created with wrong settings for browsers :

MP4 is a **container** format for holding audio/video codecs. Technically you can put any codec as long as the the other side (playback) understands it. The HTML5 video tag expects MP4 to contain H.264 video codec. Looking at your file, it won't make sense to the browser's video decoders...

[image]

You need to use a video tool to convert your current video codec to AVC codec (aka H.264) but still contained within MP4 file data. I used **[FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)** to convert and the **[result mp4](http://blog.vcone.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/vid2.mp4)** works fine in Chrome (tested on PC).

Comment: which tool you used to see these properties of video.

Comment: @user3016453, I used **[Media Player Classic](https://mpc-hc.org/)** for Windows. There you can right-click the video to see properties (under shown **MediaInfo** tab). Now actually **[MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)** is a tool that can be downloaded separately **[here](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download)** for Win, Mac or Linux.